# How do I select and change a text?

Tags: objects, text-object

I know this is a stupid question, but for some reason I can't select a text to change it. I've tried right clicking and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> but for some reason it is not letting me change what the text says. Please help.

The following should be noted:
I'm using a MacBook air,
I am using Bender 2.71, 
And I am very new to Bender.

Answer (score 16):

If the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key for some reason doesn't put you in *Edit Mode*, try changing into edit mode using the dropdown menu:

[image]

You can find more information about text editing in the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/texts/editing.html

Also, if you are a new user and do not have special reasons, there is no point in using an older version. Try the latest release, it's faster and has more features.

Comment: Note in 2.8 Object Mode / Edit mode is in the bottom left of the display.

Comment: If someone doesn't understand what to do once you're in Edit Mode, just type your text. No need to insert a cursor anywhere or select it like if you were in Photoshop.

Comment: @Skoua Thank you. As a true beginner, your comment was the solution I was looking for!